# How do I allow superclass methods to use subclass attributes in python?

Tags: python, oop

I have a simple python program that creates shapes using OOP. I'm trying to write a method in the shape class that will change behavior depending on what subclass calls it. However the behavior is not changing as it should.

This is my code:

```
class Shape:
    __shapeType = "default"

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getShapeType(self):
        return self.__shapeType

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self,centre,radius):
        super().__init__()
        self.__shapeType = "circle"
```

If I then create an instance of the `Circle` class, and call the `getShapeType` method, it returns "default". I think it has something to do with the difference between `instanceName._Circle__shapeType` and `instanceName._Shape__shapeType`, but from my current understanding of inheritance, the second one shouldn't exist in the Circle object.

What do I need to change to get this method to work as expected?

Comment: The whole point of `__these` attributes is they're name mangled so they're explicitly _not_ exposed directly to even related classes. Use `_this` (and consider a property instead of `getMethod`).

Comment: What do you mean by consider a property instead?

Comment: Basically, decorate `def getShapeType(self):` with `@property`, which will make it non-changeable (relatively so, since you can always modify the underlying `_shapeType`)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of changes to your code:

- use Python's naming convention for variable and method names(snake case).
- `__init__` in parent class does nothing basically, so simply remove it and don't call it from child.
- remove dunder before the names as Python rewrites those names with another name(it's called [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables))
- use `property` instead of defining getter method.

```py
class Shape:
    _shape_type = "default"

    @property
    def shape_type(self):
        return self._shape_type


class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, centre, radius):
        self._shape_type = "circle"


c = Circle(10, 4)
print(c.shape_type) # circle

s = Shape()
print(s.shape_type) # default
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to name mangling, change "__shapeType" to "_shapeType", for reference go to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

```py
class Shape:
    _shapeType = "default"

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getShapeType(self):
        return self._shapeType

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self,centre,radius):
        super().__init__()
        self._shapeType = "circle"
        
circle = Circle(0,0)
print(circle.getShapeType()) # This will print "circle"
```